# calculate cumulative sum and transpose from panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data stored in a csv that when read into a pandas dataframe is in the following format (the real file has many more columns but this is near enough to explain the problem):

```
        Treatment    time
0           A        12.63
1           A        83.28
2           A        83.54
3           B        85.04
4           B        85.79
5           A        131.78
```

I wish to bin by the number of each treatment in 24 hour bins and then produce a cumulative sum. I do this by:

```
bin_values = np.arange(0, 264, 24)
group_names = np.arange(0, 240, 24)

df['categories'] = pd.cut(df['time'], bin_values, labels=group_names)
```

which produces:

```
        Treatment    time    categories
0           A        12.63       0
1           A        83.28       72
2           A        83.54       72 
3           B        85.04       72
4           B        85.79       72
5           A        131.78      120
```

I can then:

```
cat_sum = df.groupby(['Treatment', 'categories'])['categories'].size()
cat_sum = cat_sum.groupby(level=[0]).cumsum().reset_index(name='cum_sum')
```

to give a data frame of the format:

```
    Treatment categories  cum_sum
0       A           0         1
1       A          72         3
2       A         120         4
3       B          72         2
```

At this point I am stuck. I wish to take this and produce something that looks like this to use with an existing visualization:

```
Treatment 0  24  48  72  96  120 144 etc ...

   A      1   1   1   3   3   4   4
   B      0   0   0   2   2   2   2
```

So essentially transpose by each treatment and add back in the missing categories to give a running total, by each 24 hour period. I've searched for along time and haven't found anything even remotely like what I need which perhaps indicates I'm going about this the wrong way.

So my question is am I going round the houses to produce what I need or is the final step just eluding me? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [df.pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

Using your example `df`:

```
    Treatment categories  cum_sum
0       A           0         1
1       A          72         3
2       A         120         4
3       B          72         2

In [1]: df.pivot(index='Treatment', columns='categories', values='cum_sum')
Out[1]: 
categories  0    72   120
Treatment                
A           1.0  3.0  4.0
B           NaN  2.0  NaN
```